# How to get the string value of a checked item in a CheckListBox which is retrieving information from an Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel

So what I want this program to do is to read an Excel file which has a list of names that was written by another program and imports them into a check list box (Which it does). This program then should allow the user to select there name and when the click the start button, takes them to a new Form Page and displays their name at the top in a LabelBox (This works, apart from the fact that what the LabelBox is returning is not the Name selected but: "System.WindowsForms.CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection....". (I am doing this by having the program write the name to a XML file so that the new Form page can read it. This is what I have:

FORM1:

```
NameListBox.CheckOnClick = true;
        NameListBox.Name = "NameListBox";
        NameListBox.TabIndex = 1;
        NameListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        NameListBox.ThreeDCheckBoxes = true;
        NameListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[2, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[3, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[4, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[5, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[6, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[7, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[8, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[9, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[10, 1].text);
        NameListBox.Items.Add(ExcelSheet.Cells[11, 1].text);
        Controls.Add(NameListBox);

        object itemChecked = NameListBox.CheckedItems;

        string SName = itemChecked.ToString();

        try
        {
            Data info = new Data();
            info.Name1 = SName;
            Login.SaveName.SaveNameData(info, "Name.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //Form2.StartUp.StudentLabelName(StudentName);
        //StudentName = Form2.NameLabel.Text;




    }

    public class SaveName
    {
        public static void SaveNameData(object obj, string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        private string name1;

        public string Name1
        {
            get { return name1; }
            set { name1 = value; }
        }
    }
```

FORM2:

```
public void StudentNames()
    {
        if (File.Exists("Name.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Login.Data));
            FileStream read = new FileStream("Name.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Login.Data info = (Login.Data)xs.Deserialize(read);
            NameLabel.Text = info.Name1;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What object type is "Data"?

Comment: NameListBox.CheckedItems is multiple items, a collection, if you only want one entry try something like: NameListBox.CheckedItems.First

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CheckedListBox.CheckedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) will return an array of objects that are checked. Loop through the CheckItems array. You can put the SNames into a list to read outside of the loop.

```
var SNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var c in NameListBox.CheckedItems)
{
    SNames.Add(c.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is good, but how do I then get SName out of the foreach loop?

Comment: I updated the answer so the values can be read outside of the loop.